# How to specify version ranges in install_requires (setuptools, distribute)

Tags: python, setuptools

I want to make a package to depend the particular version range e.g. `>= 0.5.0, < 0.7.0`.  Is it possible in `install_requires` option, and if so how should it be?

Comment: What have you tried? [The docs](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#declaring-dependencies) seem to suggest that syntax just like what you have in your question will work.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-dependencies), your syntax should work correctly. The documentation states that:

> `setuptools` and `pkg_resources` use a common syntax for specifying a project's required dependencies. This syntax consists of a project's PyPI name, optionally followed by a comma-separated list of "extras" in square brackets, optionally followed by a comma-separated list of version specifiers. A version specifier is one of the operators <, >, <=, >=, == or !=, followed by a version identifier.

The documentation gives a simple example like this:

```
docutils >= 0.3

# comment lines and \ continuations are allowed in requirement strings
BazSpam ==1.1, ==1.2, ==1.3, ==1.4, ==1.5, \
    ==1.6, ==1.7  # and so are line-end comments
```

To expand upon that, if you want your package to require a version of `docutils` greater than version 0.3 but less than version 0.5, code like this would work:

```
docutils >= 0.3, <=0.5
```

Two additional notes.

1. The documentation also states that redundant/overlapping dependency specifications will be combined internally, so `docutils >= 0.3, >=0.2` would be combined into `docutils >= 0.3`.
2. Also, be careful about specifying conflicting version numbers, which ["is meaningless and may therefore produce bizarre results."](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#declaring-dependencies) For example, I don't know why you would, but don't use this: `docutils >= 0.3, <=0.2` since this is impossible.

Comment: Great answer, but what confuses me is that the comma sometimes means **or** and sometimes **and**: the list of exact version specs clearly says '1.1 or 1.2 or ...' and combining `>= 0.3, >=0.2` to just `>=0.2` only makes sense that way. But `>= 0.3, <=0.5` or your paragraph about contradicting version specs need the comma to signify **and**.

Comment: to build on @zpea s question: is there any way to define multiple ranges of versions? e.g `(>=1.0 AND <2) OR (>=2.7 AND <2.9) OR (>=4)`

Comment: The docs say that >1, >2 become >1, but it would make more sense to become >2, as you said. Anyone knows why?

Comment: Multiple == with different versions won't find any version to install since comma "," is always **and**. I was curious enough to find the example in setuptools 3.0 documentation and implementation seems to be in distutils versionpredicate. Looking back to 3.2 version in 2012, it seems to have always returned false, if any of the listed version specifiers do not match.

Answer (score 20):

Be wary of involuntary beta tests. Package maintainers sometimes release incompatible, incomplete, or broken a, b, and c releases to general audiences without warning. The next time you run **setup.py** in a fresh virtualenv, you might pull down one of these poisoned eggs, and suddenly your program will break.

To mitigate this risk, *do not use* the `foo >=0.3, <0.4` style declaration, which has a purely numeric upper bound. `<0.4` still admits versions 0.4a0, 0.4a1, 0.4b0, 0.4c3, etc. Instead, use an upper bound like `<0.4a0`, as in `foo >=0.3, <0.4a0`, when you write your **install_requires**.

When **setuptools** does something unexpected, trying using **verlib** to model your version comparisons. Verlib is a pretty good fit as long as your versions are normalized and non-contradictory. Here is an example that demonstrates the potentially counter-intuitive ordering of normalized versions:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from verlib import NormalizedVersion as V

assert (V("0.7.9") < V("0.8a0") < V("0.8a1") < V("0.8b0") < V("0.8b1")
    < V("0.8b2") < V("0.8.0") < V("0.8.1a0") < V("0.8.1") < V("0.9")
    < V("1.0a3") < V("1.0b2") < V("1.0b20") < V("1.0c0") < V("1.0")
    < V("1.0.1"))

assert (V("0.7.9") < V("0.8.0a0") < V("0.8.0a1") < V("0.8.0b0")
    < V("0.8.0b1") < V("0.8.0b2") < V("0.8.0") < V("0.8.1a0") < V("0.8.1")
    < V("0.9") < V("1.0a3") < V("1.0b2") < V("1.0b20") < V("1.0c0")
    < V("1.0") < V("1.0.1"))

print "Version comparisons are sane."
```

Comment: How do you use verlib in your setup.py file (`install_requires`)?

Answer (score 4):

The notation mentioned in OP's question, `>= 0.5.0, < 0.7.0`, already works.

And, since many (if not most) of the libraries would already use [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/), so by definition you can define your dependency as `A>=1,<2`, as [explained here](https://packaging.python.org/discussions/install-requires-vs-requirements/#install-requires). And they even implemented [an even simpler syntax for it, `A~=X.Y`](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#semantic-versioning-preferred), meaning it requires at least release X.Y, but also allows any later release with a matching MAJOR version.

Comment: info: semantic versioning is a 3-part MAJOR.MINOR.MAINTENANCE numbering scheme

Answer (score 3):

The answer for OP question including the `install_requires` would be looks like this:

```py
setuptools.setup(
    ...
    install_requires=['package>=0.5.0,< 0.7.0']
    ...
    )
```

Other example with extra rejecting certain version based on others [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30040341/11671779):

```py
setuptools.setup(
    ...
    install_requires=['package>=1.4.2,<1.9,!=1.5.*,!=1.6.*']
    ...
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to it is to use wildcards.

This does not apply to >= 0.5.0, < 0.7.0, but in case you decide that all maintenance releases should be supported (e.g. 0.5.0 to 0.5.x), you can use

== 0.5.*

e.g.
docutils == 0.3.*

Comment: This is the only setup tools example I found after several sites which shows setup.py syntax for equals, `==`; I was getting version numbers from my Anaconda requirements file and it uses `=`. I got confused.