# How to write a python setup script to require particular version of pyparsing

Tags: python, distutils, pyparsing

I have a setup.py script which knows about the dependency on pyparsing, and will in fact install it.  But it is grabbing the latest version, 2.0.0, which (apparently) is incompatible with python 2.x.  It looks like I need to be able to limit the installer to versions 1.5.x of pyparsing, but could not find a way to tell the setup.py script about such a restriction, or if such is even possible.

My setup.py is using setuptools.setup, and lists pyparsing in the install_requires section.

Comment: Doesn't `install_requires = ['pyparsing>=1.5<2']` do the trick?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to specify version ranges in install\_requires (setuptools, distribute)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11472810/how-to-specify-version-ranges-in-install-requires-setuptools-distribute)

Comment: @sr2222: Almost; needed a comma after the 5.