# Matching any version in a range

Tags: python, setuptools

I have a package which depends on quite a few packages. I usually express my dependencies like this:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    # ...
    install_requires = [ 'setuptools',
        'django == 1.5',
        'django-pipeline == 1.3.12',
    ],
    # ...
)
```

However, certain projects like `django-pipeline` release often with bugfixes and minor updates. How can I specify that `setuptools` should use anything in the range of `1\.3\.[0-9]+`? (Essentially: `1.3.x`)

Is there a way to do this in `setuptools`?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11472810/how-to-specify-version-ranges-in-install-requires-setuptools-distribute