# Bundling a library so easier to maintain?

Tags: python, version-control

I am releasing a small spectroscopy library soon and I've developed it using numpy 1.8, pandas 0.14 and matplotlib 1.4.  In both pandas and matplotlib, new features/API changes in the next release are certainly going to break some functionality in my code.  In fact, the pandas API change is so drastic for our needs, that it would require me to refactor 3 core classes in my code.  But I'd have to maintain the old classes for backwards compatibility...

I'm a PhD student and don't have much time to maintain my code for every update in these libraries in the near future.  My solution is to bundle a few modules from the current versions of the dependency libraries, and then hopefully in the future make a more compatible API.

This really feels like a bad solution, but I can't count on being available to keep the library up to date with every API change of the dependencies.  What advice do you have in this regard?  An alternative is to encourage users to work in a virtual env., but that's a lot to ask them to configure just to test out my library.

Thanks

Comment: `sudo pip install virtualenv`, what's so hard about that? Good programming practice is to use a virtual environment anyway.

Comment: Is there a one-liner that will create the virtual environment from my requirements?

My audience is non-programmers.  They're going to be unhappy to not have a binary to doubleclick install anyway, so as soon as I say "oh just set up a virtual environment.  It's really easy.  Then activate it when you want to use my library.  Just open a terminal, activate, make sure you have a venvs folder etc... then deactive when you are done".  For a non-techinal user, they are lost at "open a terminal"

Comment: Does your library have a setup.py?

Comment: Ya, sure:

https://github.com/hugadams/pyuvvis/blob/master/setup.py

Comment: Use `install_requires` in your setup.py and specify a version.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11472810/how-to-specify-version-ranges-in-install-requires-setuptools-distribute

Comment: Thanks.  So you think that it's ok to lock users into an older version of a code this way?  And say that if they have another version, set up a virtual env?

Comment: It's probably not best but for your situation it seems the easiest way for you and the user. At least for now.

Comment: Alternatively, you could try to package up a standalone file for users too, using something like [PyInstaller](https://github.com/pyinstaller) - if `numpy`, `pandas` and `matplotlib` are the main dependencies, then they're apparently [all supported](http://www.pyinstaller.org/wiki/SupportedPackages).

Comment: Yes, maybe I will.  Thanks Steven.