# Exclude certain dependency version ranges in setuptools/pip

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

Currently the Django Project supports 1.4, 1.7 and 1.8. In my `setup.py` I want to reflect these versions as being supported.

```
install_requires=['Django>=1.4.2,<1.8.99,!=1.5,!=1.6']
```

However this still allows 1.5.x and 1.6.x releases. How can I exclude a complete range?

[Setuptools lists](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/pkg_resources.html#requirements-parsing) the following valid requirements as an example:

```
PickyThing<1.6,>1.9,!=1.9.6,<2.0a0,==2.4c1
```

However this doesn't work with pip (it should at least match 1.4.x / 1.5.x):

> No matching distribution found for PickyThing!=1.9.6,<1.6,<2.0a0,==2.4c1,>1.9

**Update with example**
For example; I only want to include [currently supported versions of Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/download/). This would be 1.4.x, 1.7.x and 1.8.x. So I would write;

```
#setup.py
install_requires=['Django>=1.4.2,<1.4.99,>=1.7,<1.8.99']
```

However if I run `pip install -e .` on this project, it fails with;

```
Collecting Django<1.4.99,<1.8.99,>=1.4.2,>=1.7 (from ...)
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Django<1.4.99,<1.8.99,>=1.4.2,>=1.7 (from django-two-factor-auth==1.2.0) (from versions: 1.1.3, 1.1.4, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.2.5, 1.2.6, 1.2.7, 1.3, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 1.3.4, 1.3.5, 1.3.6, 1.3.7, 1.4, 1.4.1, 1.4.2, 1.4.3, 1.4.4, 1.4.5, 1.4.6, 1.4.7, 1.4.8, 1.4.9, 1.4.10, 1.4.11, 1.4.12, 1.4.13, 1.4.14, 1.4.15, 1.4.16, 1.4.17, 1.4.18, 1.4.19, 1.4.20, 1.5, 1.5.1, 1.5.2, 1.5.3, 1.5.4, 1.5.5, 1.5.6, 1.5.7, 1.5.8, 1.5.9, 1.5.10, 1.5.11, 1.5.12, 1.6, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.6.6, 1.6.7, 1.6.8, 1.6.9, 1.6.10, 1.6.11, 1.7, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.7.3, 1.7.4, 1.7.5, 1.7.6, 1.7.7, 1.7.8, 1.8a1, 1.8b1, 1.8b2, 1.8rc1, 1.8, 1.8.1)
No matching distribution found for Django<1.4.99,<1.8.99,>=1.4.2,>=1.7 (from ...)
```

It is obvious that a version number 1.4.20 cannot satisfy `>=1.7` and 1.8.1 cannot satisfy `<1.4.99`. However the documentation from Setuptools (see above) does suggest that something along these lines should be possible. However, this is non-obvious to me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use

```
Django>=1.4.2,<1.9,!=1.5.*,!=1.6.*
```

This is defined inside [PEP440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#version-specifiers).

You can test this behavior with the [packaging](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/packaging) module that is vendored inside the last versions of setuptools and pip.

```
In [1]: from packaging import specifiers

In [2]: sp=specifiers.SpecifierSet(">=1.4.2,<1.9,!=1.5.*,!=1.6.*")

In [3]: sp.contains("1.4.2")
Out[3]: True

In [4]: sp.contains("1.6.4")
Out[4]: False

In [5]: sp.contains("1.8.2")
Out[5]: True
```

Comment: ```install_requires=['Django>=1.4.2,<1.9,!=1.5.*,!=1.6.*']```

Answer (score 4):

I've read some related code of `pkg_resources`. I think the document [here](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/pkg_resources.html#requirement-objects) is not accurate. Not only `pip` fails to find the right package version, `python setup.py install`, which actually uses `setuptools`, also fails.

Some of the related code:

*pip/_vendor/packaging/specifiers.py*

```
# If we have any specifiers, then we want to wrap our iterable in the
# filter method for each one, this will act as a logical AND amongst
# each specifier.
if self._specs:
    for spec in self._specs:
        iterable = spec.filter(iterable, prereleases=prereleases)
    return iterable
```

You can see that in the comment, the author emphasized that this will cause an `AND` amongst each specifier, not `OR`. So if you do this:

```
PickyThing<1.6,>1.9,!=1.9.6,<2.0a0,==2.4c1
```

You will get nothing!

I tried with this code below:

```
import pkg_resources

a = ['1.4', '1.8', '1.9.2']
d = pkg_resources.Requirement.parse('PickyThing<1.6,>1.9,!=1.9.6')
r = d.specifier.filter(a)

print(list(r)) # Nothing, just an empty list []
```

You may want to file a bug to [pip](https://github.com/pypa/pip) so they can fix it.

Comment: Thanks for investigating I'll award the bounty, once available. I've submitted [a bug report](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2744) to pip.

Comment: The nonsensical example of `PickyThing<1.6,>1.9,!=1.9.6,<2.0a0,==2.4c1 ` was removed in https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/pull/2121 (commas mean logical AND)