# Pip installing wrong version of a dependency - django

Tags: django, python-2.7, pip

I am running an old RHEL5 server and would like to install a beta version of the python module `openrem` from pip.

I create a virtual env in my folder and issue the command

`pip install openrem==0.7.0b13`

The `setup.py` for openrem 0.7.0b13 has the following requirements

```
requires = [
    'django>=1.8,<1.9',
    'django-filter >= 0.10',
    'pytz >= 0a',
    'humanize',
    'pydicom >= 0.9.9',
    'django-pagination',
    'xlsxwriter',
    'celery >= 3.1',
    'argparse >= 1.2.1',
    'django-qsstats-magic',
    'python-dateutil',
    'django-solo',
    'django-crispy-forms'
    ]
```

However, I get the following message during the installation

```
Downloading/unpacking django>=1.8,<1.9 (from openrem==0.7.0b13)
Downloading Django-1.9rc1.tar.gz (7.3MB): 7.3MB downloaded
Running setup.py egg_info for package django
```

Low and behold django 1.9 is installed. The problem being `openrem` is incompatible with `django 1.9`. Why is pip ignoring the requirement to install `django <1.9`

Comment: Which version of pip do you use? `pip install 'django>=1.8,<1.9'` installs 1.8.12 for me, under pip 8.1.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All I've managed to dig up is this:

> To mitigate this risk, do not use the foo >=0.3, <0.4 style
>   declaration, which has a purely numeric upper bound. <0.4 still admits
>   versions 0.4a0, 0.4a1, 0.4b0, 0.4c3, etc. Instead, use an upper bound
>   like <0.4a0, as in foo >=0.3, <0.4a0, when you write your
>   install_requires.

from: [How to specify version ranges in install_requires (setuptools, distribute)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11472810/how-to-specify-version-ranges-in-install-requires-setuptools-distribute)

Perhaps you need to be more specific. You probably end up with django v 1.9.5 right? Seems a bit stupid, but there's probably some reason for it!